# Process.GetProcessesByName Doesn't work on exe

Tags: c#

```
if (!Main.isAttached)
                {
                    num++;
                    if (num <= 15)
                    {  
                        try
                        {
                            Main.gameProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo")[0];
                            if ((Main.gameProcess == null || !Main.IsModuleLoaded(Main.gameProcess, "client_panorama.dll") ? true : !Main.IsModuleLoaded(Main.gameProcess, "engine.dll")))
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(exception);
                            continue;
                        }
                        while (true)
                        {
                            if ((Main.clientPanoramaDll == null ? false : Main.engineDll != null))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                            Main.clientPanoramaDll = Main.GetModuleHandle(Main.gameProcess, "client_panorama.dll");
                            Main.engineDll = Main.GetModuleHandle(Main.gameProcess, "engine.dll");
                        }
                        Main.isAttached = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("CSGO Not Open!", "Open the game first.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
                        base.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

I am trying to program a mod for CSGO but it says it cannot detect the game is opened when it is already opened! I tried changing It to csgo.exe, csgo.exe32, but nothing works. Any tips please?

Comment: What is the return value of `Process.GetProcesses()`, is there anything similar to what you are looking for? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I made an edit to my post so youll see the full code

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share with us your `IsModuleLoaded()` function so we can't answer this question, but here is the code I use which should solve your problem:

```
public static IntPtr GetModuleBaseAddress(Process proc, string modName)
{
    IntPtr addr = IntPtr.Zero;

    foreach (ProcessModule m in proc.Modules)
    {
        if (m.ModuleName == modName)
        {
            addr = m.BaseAddress;
            break;
        }
    }
    return addr;
}

Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo")[0];

var modBase = ghapi.GetModuleBaseAddress(proc, "client.dll");
```

You can check the return value of GetModuleBaseAddress, if it's equal to IntPtr.Zero then the module was not loaded.  It also will serve as the module handle, so you don't need additional redundant code.